# Keeping TAdoConnection alive

Tags: sql-server, delphi, ado

In one of the question here:
[How can I detect that a TadoConnection lost the communication with the server?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2289260/3906993)

It was suggested to create a Timer and poll the SQL server.

From the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2289833/3906993):

> TTimer is OK. The query should be performed in a thread, where the
>   corresponding connection is used. Not a must although, but it is a
>   different issue.

Should I use the same/main connection (in the DM of the main thread) or should I create a **new** connection in the timer event to "ping" the SQL server?

Is polling the SQL server will help keeping the connection alive in the first place?

Comment: There is no problem to use the same(main) connection in main thread . "Is polling the SQL server will help keeping the connection alive in the first place?" No.

Comment: But I think that the use of a separate thread is properly

Comment: Bear in mind ADO uses COM, which is thread-specific. Meaning an ADO connection cannot be shared in different threads.

Comment: @JerryDodge, Thanks. I am fully aware of that. So what do you suggest then?

Answer (score 0):

Using a timer to poll connection is a bad idea. Doing unneccessary polls consumes resources and is generally bad concept of your application design.

The best way to restore a broken connection is to start using is again in `try` block and then re-establish it within `except..end` block. Take a look at this piece of code:

```
// Re-establishes connection every time it gets broken
procedure RespawnConnection;
begin
  FConnection := TADOConnection.Create(nil);
  FADODataSet := TADODataSet.Create(nil);
  with FConnection do
  begin
    ConnectionString := AdoConnectionString; // your CS here
    LoginPrompt := False;
    Connected := True;
  end;
  FADODataSet.Connection := FConnection;
end;

// An exposed method to do ADO queries
function Query(const sql: string): TADODataSet;
begin
  try
    Result := FADODataSet;
    FADODataSet.CommandText := sql; // if FADODataSet is not assigned,
                                    // this line throws an excepion...
    FADODataSet.Open;
  except
    RespawnConnection; // ...which is properly handled here...
    Result := Query(sql); // ...and then repeats the query
  end;
end;
```

Don't forget to free both objects in `FormClose` event (unless they are components on your form).

In case of *heavy* and *time-consuming* queries, it may be worth to offload the whole ADO stuff to a separate thread. Running such query in a separate thread would be more efficient in terms of user experience. Once `const sql: string` is passed to a thread, the thread will do the magic, while user keeps interacting with the main form.

If you're up to implement a *separate thread* concept, don't forget to call `CoInitialize` and `CoUninizialize` because ADO is based on COM (as Jerry mentined) and uses appartment-threaded objects.